# What's wrong with my code, it seems correctly, but it's not

Tags: java, priority-queue

The problem is I have to read a text file. I have 24 candidates, and each number from 1-24 is correspond to candidates 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...., 24. (I.e: if the digit 1 is seen 10 times in the text file then it means the first candidate has 10 votes. However, I don't know why I am able to print out first 9 candidates only. I want to print out everyone, can anyone tell me where I went wrong?
This is my votes.txt:  cs.jhu.edu/~jason/226/hw6/data/ballots 
So, here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class ElectionTieBreaker {
    static String line;
    public static int highestLocation(int[] x){
        int max = 0, value = 0; 
        for (int i=0; i<x.length; i++){ 
            if (x[i] > max){ 
                max = x[i];
                value = i;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        PriorityQueue<Integer> listpeople = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();

        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\votes.txt");

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(file);

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(line);
            listpeople.add(a);
        }
        in.close();
        int[] candidates = new int[24];
        for (int i = 0; i <= listpeople.size(); i++) {
            int x = listpeople.poll();
            candidates[x-1]++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            int next = highestLocation(candidates);
            System.out.println((next+1) + " " + candidates[next]);
            candidates[next] = 0;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Each time you call `listpeople.poll()` it reduces the size of the `listpeople` list, there fore you exit condition for loop is been met early...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thank you, I think I see it. May you suggest me how I can fix this?

Comment: Use something like `while (!listpeople.isEmpty()) {` instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `poll`, it reduces the size of the `PriorityQueue`, but you are incrementing `i` each time you do it.  This means that `i` and the size of the `PriorityQueue` meet in the middle.

Consider using something more like...

```
while (!listpeople.isEmpty()) {
    int x = listpeople.poll();
    candidates[x - 1]++;
}
```

All this does it continues to loop until there are no more elements in the `PriorityQueue`...